# Multiplying the sum of numbers in a column with the sum of numbers in another column? Access to C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

This program displays database information in a Data Grid View. I need to add all the numbers in column 1, add all the numbers in column 3, and multiply the two sums together.

This code only multiplies column 1 and column 3 from the last row. Any suggestions?

This is my first time connecting to a database, so I apologize if this seems like a dumb question

```
                foreach (DataRow currentRow in itemDS.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    // add to data grid view
                    invoiceDataGridView.Rows.Add(currentRow[1].ToString(),   currentRow[2].ToString(), currentRow[3].ToString());

                    var itemQuant = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow[1]);
                    var priceEach = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow[3]);

                    decimal subTotal = itemQuant * priceEach;

                    subTotalOutput.Text = subTotal.ToString();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you're not sure how to keep a running total in the looping construction? If so:

```
decimal total = 0; //declare outside the foreach

foreach (DataRow currentRow in itemDS.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    // add to data grid view
                    invoiceDataGridView.Rows.Add(currentRow[1].ToString(),   currentRow[2].ToString(), currentRow[3].ToString());

                    var itemQuant = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow[1]);
                    var priceEach = Convert.ToDecimal(currentRow[3]);

                    decimal subTotal = itemQuant * priceEach;

                    total += subTotal;
                }

//do something with total here, after for each finishes
```

Comment: Ahhh yes! Thank you so much. Thant worked exactly like I needed it to :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq for taking sum of a column.

```
var sum = itemDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Sum(dr => dr.Field<int>("value"));
```

`"value"` will be the column name of the datatable inside the itemDS. you have to specify your column name here.

Take the sum of next column like the above statement. add multiply it..

Hope this helps.. :)